# How to code an object that is specific to a logged in user

Tags: c#, list, design-patterns, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I am coding a C# MVC5 internet application and I have a question about the model structure.

I am wanting a user to register and once registered, the user can create some MapLocation objects. Because each MapLocation object belongs to a user, I wish to be able to find all MapLocations that have been created by a user, how do I code the models?

I am thinking of two screnarios, but either of these could not be correct.

Scenario 1:

I code a UserInfo class, and add this to the ApplicationUser class when a user registers. This UserInfo class has a List of MapLocations. Whenever a MapLocation is created, it is added to the List of MapLocations in the UserInfo class of the specific user.

Scenario 2:

I have a string variable in the MapLocation object that stores the logged in user's name. Whenever I create a MapLocation object, the logged in user's name is added to this MapLocation object. I can then search for MapLocations based on the string variable.

Are either of the above scenarios the one to go with? Is there a better way to do this? Is there a specific design pattern that caters to this situation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I go with the former, from the OOP perspective IMO it seems the better choice. I wouldn't want a MapLocation object to be aware of a user at all. Or i would create a MapLocationManager, which internally holds a `LookUp` mapping a UserId to the list of MapLocations he created, that way i can elimnate the ApplicationUser from being incharge of managing the MapLocations, which may cause you to move the ApplicationUser class to all the places inside your code the need to access those MapLocations.

Comment: If I add a UserInfo class to the ApplicationUser class, and this has MapLocations, will these values be encrypted when saved in the database. By that, I mean, can I look through the tables if needed, and the data in the table will be readable, and not encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your "comment" on Yuval's answer, here is a third solution which would likely be better in case of getting the data onto a database/server.

```
Class UserInfo - Credentials/Login Info - Preferences
private list<int> _ownedMapLocations;
```

MapLocationClass

```
Class MapLocations 
private int _id;
```

Database concept of keys, will allow you to store them properly/efficiently in the databse (normalization). It would also be possible for an "user" share it's MapLocation easily or to copy someone else into his own set.